# Question about pointers in adding 2 numbers from 2 linked lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am now learning the topics from leetcode, and there is a question about adding 2 numbers from 2 linked list. Example is as follows:

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807
```

When I went through the solution here:

```
def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        p1 = l1 
        p2 = l2
        carry = 0 

        head=p3=ListNode(0)

        while p1 or p2 or carry: 
            if p1:
                carry += p1.val
                p1 = p1.next
            if p2:
                carry += p2.val
                p2 = p2.next

            p3.val = carry % 10 
            carry = carry // 10

            if p1 or p2 or carry: 
                p3.next = ListNode(0)
                p3 = p3.next

        return head
```

For the return value, I got a issue here. 
When I return p3 instead of return head directly, then it returns the last value i.e 8

However, when I return head, then it returns the whole linked list i.e  7 -> 0 -> 8
And within the wile loop there is nothing related with head.

What is the logic behind, when the p3 value was returned to head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because in this [chained assignement](https://www.reddit.com/r/pythontips/comments/526alb/python_chained_assignment_ab0/):

`head=p3=ListNode(0)`

You are setting both `head` and `p3` to point to the initially created ListNode (which eventually holds number 7).

However in this line of the `while` loop:

```
p3 = p3.next
```

You update p3 to point to the newly created ListNode.

Thus at the end of the `while` loop, `head` will still point to the first ListNode (because nothing happens to it in the `while` loop), but `p3` will point to the last created ListNode because it is being constantly updated.

Comment: Thanks! But a question here: when the head always points to the first ListNode 
and p3 points to the last created ListNode in every single round in the loop, how can the   first ListNode be updated? 
Or in another words, why the first ListNode receive the value from p3?

Comment: This is a [chained assignment](https://www.reddit.com/r/pythontips/comments/526alb/python_chained_assignment_ab0/), meaning you are assigning the same ListNode object to both head and p3.

Comment: The first ListNode is updated in the very first iteration of the loop. On the line p3.val = carry % 10, you update the value of p3 with the digit that is the result of the addition. Since head and p3 are pointing to the same ListNode object, head will also "see" this change. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi, sweet and clear --- this answered my doubt. Thanks again for the big help =)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the lists to numpy arrays and then add the two arrays and then reverse the linked list.

```
import numpy as np
l1 = [2, 4, 3]
l2 = [5, 6, 4]
l3 = np.array(l1) + np.array(l2)
l3[::-1]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: actually the question provided 2 linked list instead of normal list as input....I actually thought of converting the linked list to list but I failed to do so. Do you know how can I make it?
Thank you for your answer anyways =)

Comment: if you add ```[::-1]``` behind any python list, tuple... and it will reverse it. And the reason I'm doing in the end is because I can save some computation when only doing it once, and it will still have the same effect